# Why is implicit conversion not occurring

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

Why is my conversion constructor not working? The explicit conversion compiles fine.

```
struct element {};

struct element_set {
    element_set(const element& e) : e(e) {};
    element_set& operator+(const element& e) { return *this; }

    const element &e;
};

element e1, e2;

auto es1 = element_set(e1) + e2; 
auto es2 = e1 + e2;

kent:kas kent$ g++ -std=c++14 -g implicit.cc
implicit.cc:13:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('element' and 'element')
auto es2 = e1 + e2;
           ~~ ^ ~~
1 error generated.
```

Based on the answer from @Krizz and comment from @BenVoigt below, I can get implicit conversion working by adding a friend to element_set:

```
struct element_set {
    element_set(const element& e) : e(e) {};
    element_set& operator+(const element& e) { return *this; }
    friend element_set operator+(const element& l, const element& r);
    const element &e;
};

element_set operator+(const element& l, const element& r) { return l+r; }
```

Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: User-defined conversions do not operate on the implicit object argument.

Comment: `operator+` doesn't have to be a member function.  Try as a friend function (with two arguments)...

Comment: `operator+` returning a reference is a bad idea too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, where you use operators, is equivalent to:

```
element e1, e2;
auto es1 = element_set(e1).operator+(e2); 
auto es2 = e1.operator+(e2);
```

Can you see now why this does not work?
There is no method `operator+` on `struct element`. So, the only thing compilator can try are reachable functions of form:

```
R operator+(TypeConvertibleFromElement, TypeConvertibleFromElement)
```

No such a function exists.

*Note*: The above is for explanatory purposes only. Discussing the C++ language specification and how compilers work would require a little bit more precise descriptions.

Comment: Right. If I want automatic conversion, I need to add a conversion operator to element. Thanks.